# How to add a list of hyperlinks in a CSV field to a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: python, list, csv, google-sheets, hyperlink

I'm generating a csv file (with thousands of rows) on my local PC. *From a Google account, I would like to do a manual Google Sheets>Import to upload the file for my book club group.* The data is collected from HTML tables on multiple pages, if that matters.

One of the fields is named "shelves" is essentially tags, and it contains a list of `(name, url)` tuples. I'd like to modify my Python program to make a list along the lines of 
`[=HYPERLINK(url, name), =HYPERLINK(url, name), ..., =HYPERLINK(url, name)]`
but I can't find any syntax clues. I also tried 
`['=HYPERLINK("url", "name"), =HYPERLINK("url", "name")', '=HYPERLINK("url", "name"), =HYPERLINK("url", "name")', ...]`

Can something like this via *importing a CSV file from Google Sheets* work or not, in Aug 2022?

Here's a sample CSV row:

```
,title,title_url,author,author_url,shelves,date_started,date_finished,member_name,member_url,date_added,group_activity,group_book_id_url'
'29,"Luck in the Shadows (Nightrunner, #1)",http://goodreads.com/book/show/74270.Luck_in_the_Shadows,"Flewelling, Lynn",http://goodreads.com/author/show/42110.Lynn_Flewelling,"[('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=read', 'read'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=1-book-of-the-month', '1-book-of-the-month'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=char-royalty-nobility', 'char-royalty-nobi...'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-action-adventure', 'genre-action-adve...'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-epic', 'genre-epic'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-fantasy', 'genre-fantasy'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-romance', 'genre-romance'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=profession-mage-witch-wizard', 'profession-mage-w...'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=theme-cross-dressing', 'theme-cross-dressing'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=theme-nautical', 'theme-nautical'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=theme-on-the-run', 'theme-on-the-run'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=time-historical', 'time-historical')]",1/1/2021,1/31/2021,Marianne ,http://goodreads.com/user/show/marianne,"group activity for 536628',http://goodreads.com/group/show_book/group?group_book_id=536628
```

So `shelves` is the field I'm working on. As you can see it has a long list (and edited for brevity):

```
[('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=read', 'read'),  ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-action-adventure', 'genre-action-adve...'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-epic', 'genre-epic'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-fantasy', 'genre-fantasy'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-romance', 'genre-romance'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=profession-mage-witch-wizard', 'profession-mage-w...'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=theme-on-the-run', 'theme-on-the-run'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=time-historical', 'time-historical')]
```

I would like to have a csv-type file that can be *manually imported into Google Sheets* and have a single cell contain the `shelves` list in the following fashion:
`[=HYPERTEXT('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=read', 'read'), =HYPERTEXT('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-action-adventure', 'genre-action-adve...')]

So that when it is uploaded to Google it displays similarly to an html table cell: [image: shelf tags from Goodreads]

Before I go through a ton of iterations of that, I wanted to see if that would even work. All the research I've done has come up with mostly 2020 info about only being able to do this in the Google Apps environment, or to possibly write a function for the spreadsheet. I did sign up and try the Google Apps environment, but got stuck in setting up credentials.

If not, is there a best approach to somehow accomplish this?

If it is possible, I could use some help on the syntax. Thank you!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample CSV data and the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: Thank you for checking. I've added to my original post. Does that help clarify?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your question. In order to achieve your goal, I think that there are several directions. For example, which do you want to achieve your goal using googleapis for python or pygsheets for python or gspread for python or Google Apps Script? By the way, your CSV data is existing in your local PC?

Comment: Thanks! The libraries you mention all require an initial Google Developer credentials setup in order to use the apis. I don't want to use the api. I want to manually Import a text file into Google, not do an automated client login. My question is is there is a text formula that Google can convert to Hyperlinks?

Comment: Reworded the process flow bits. Really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to put the values from local PC to Google Spreasheet without API using a python script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Almost correct. More like Use Google Sheets to upload a local PC text file in CSV format so that Google displays a single cell with a list of URLs. I want correct formatting so that a local CSV file contains a single field entry that contains a single list of multiple properly formatted Google list HYPERLINKs.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Almost correct.`, I understood that I cannot still correctly understand your question. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Absolutely! Just happy that you are thinking on it. Any help is immensely appreciated. It seems like it should be simple to translate a field containing a list of URLs in a CSV file to Google Sheets, and display in Sheets as a list of URLs in a single cell, using formula formatting --without having to be a Google Developer, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to upload CSV data of your local PC to your Google Drive.

  - Here, from your question, the uploading data is as follows.

    ```
      [('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=read', 'read'),  ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-action-adventure', 'genre-action-adve...'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-epic', 'genre-epic'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-fantasy', 'genre-fantasy'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-romance', 'genre-romance'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=profession-mage-witch-wizard', 'profession-mage-w...'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=theme-on-the-run', 'theme-on-the-run'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=time-historical', 'time-historical')]
    ```
- You want to create a new Spreadsheet and put the formulas like `=HYPERLINK("url", "name")` to the column "A" of the new Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using a python script. And, when the data is uploaded, you don't want to authorize the scopes.

Unfortunately, when the data is uploaded to Google Drive, authorization is required to be used. So, in this answer, in order to achieve your goal, as a workaround, I used Web Apps as a wrapper API. When Web Apps is used, the authorization can be done when the Web Apps is deployed. By this, when the script accesses the Web Apps, the data can be uploaded without authorization. In this case, how about the following method?

### Usage:

#### 1. Create a Google Apps Script project.

In order to use Web Apps, please create a new Google Apps Script project. When you access https://script.google.com/home and create a new project. You can create a new Google Apps Script project.

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the created Google Apps Script project.

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  const newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create("sample");
  const formulas = data.map(([a, b]) => [`=HYPERLINK("${a}", "${b}")`]);
  newSS.getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, formulas.length, 1).setFormulas(formulas);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(newSS.getUrl());
}
```

- In this case, as a sample, a new Spreadsheet is created to the root folder.
- If you want to achieve your goal without using `=HYPERLINK()`, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const formulas = data.map(([a, b]) => [`=HYPERLINK("${a}", "${b}")`]);
      newSS.getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, formulas.length, 1).setFormulas(formulas);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const rValues = data.map(([a, b]) => [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(b).setLinkUrl(a).build()]);
      newSS.getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, rValues.length).setRichTextValues(rValues);
    ```

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

The detailed information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Please set this using the new IDE of the script editor.

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. Copy the URL of the Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
   - You can see the detail of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### 4. Testing:

In order to test the above Web Apps, in this case, from your question, a python script and your showing data are used. The sample script is as follows. Before you use this, please set `url`.

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec" # Please replace this with your Web Apps URL.

# This data is from your question.
data = [('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=read', 'read'),  ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-action-adventure', 'genre-action-adve...'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-epic', 'genre-epic'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-fantasy', 'genre-fantasy'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=genre-romance', 'genre-romance'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=profession-mage-witch-wizard', 'profession-mage-w...'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=theme-on-the-run', 'theme-on-the-run'), ('http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf/group?shelf=time-historical', 'time-historical')]

res = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data))
print(res.text)
```

- From your question, I understood that you have already had `data` in the above script. So, I used it.
- When this script is run, your `data` is sent to Web Apps without the authorization. Because the authorization has already been done when Web Apps is deployed. The uploaded data is parsed and set the values as the formula. And, the URL of the created new Spreadsheet is returned.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: I think this may answer my question, and it will help clarify some of my confusion. I'll have to work through all the doc links you provided. Sorry, Google is overwhelming with everything being named very similarly and unclear to a non-Google person what's what. https://script.google.com/home comes up for me with my loaded spreadsheets displayed so, I'm hopeful this is it.

Comment: @Meghan M. Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Above response was nothing important. Overall, after looking through the docs and following the processes, I think the answer to my question is "Google's Import cannot automatically translate a field containing a list of URLs into a field containing a list of Hyperlinks, regardless of the format used in the CSV field. The user can write an Extension using Google Apps Scripts. The user can reuse that script for their other Google Sheets."

Answer (score 0):

Google's *Import* function cannot automatically translate a field containing a list of URLs into a single field as a list of Hyperlinks, regardless of the URL format used in the CSV field.

The user must write a Google Sheet Extension using  *Extensions > Apps Scripts* in the relevant Sheet. Thanks to Tanaike's Answer that supplies comprehensive directions.

The user can then copy that script to their other Google Sheets that Import similarly formatted files.