# Convert a list of URL pairs to a list of hyperlinks in Google Sheets cell using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a refinement of my question [How to add a list of hyperlinks in a CSV field to a cell in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347973/how-to-add-a-list-of-hyperlinks-in-a-csv-field-to-a-cell-in-google-sheets). Since it turns out this can only be done through Google Sheets>Extensions Apps Script, I definitely do not have enough knowledge of javascript.
I do know:
a) I do NOT need to have Developer Credentials
b) I can apply the custom script to any directly-related Google Sheets 
c) Most of the formatting can be done on my local CSV file through Python. That means I'm only concerned about the particular column where each cell is a list of URL/text pairs
I've gone with a simple formatting where each url/text pair is separated by `"; "` and the url and text are separated by `", "`. The data in each cell is a list in the format:

```
http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf?shelf=read, read; http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf?shelf=genre-fairytale-folklore, genre-fairytale-f...; http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf?shelf=genre-romance, genre-romance; http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf?shelf=theme-humor, theme-humor
```

I would like my results to be a cell containing a list of hyperlinks `read, genre-fairytale-folklore, genre-romance, theme-humor`.

I've gotten as far as

```
function myFunction() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  for(n=0;n<values.length;n++) {
    var cell = values[n][3];
    var cell_split = cell.split("; ");
```

It works to that point but `cell_split.split(", ")` doesn't work and `cell_split.getLinkUrl()` isn't a function. I'm not sure where to go from there. Thank you!

Other sources:
[Updated Specification of Google Spreadsheet: Multiple Hyperlinks to a Cell](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d39b4b5ccc5a1d50f5b8b75febd807a6) by Tanaike

[Add links to cell in Google Sheets](https://spreadsheet.dev/add-links-to-a-cell-in-google-sheets-using-apps-scripts)

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my sample script was not useful for your situation. From your question, by guessing your situation, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images? By this, I would like to modify the proposed script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- You have the values like `http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf?shelf=read, read; http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf?shelf=genre-fairytale-folklore, genre-fairytale-f...; http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf?shelf=genre-romance, genre-romance; http://goodreads.com/group/bookshelf?shelf=theme-humor, theme-humor` each cell of the column "D".
- You want to convert these values to `read, genre-fairytale-folklore, genre-romance, theme-humor` including URLs.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

When I saw your showing script, in this case, you split the cell value by `;`. But, unfortunately, your script is not set the URLs. So, in this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("D1:D" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([d]) => {
    if ([";", ","].every(e => !d.getText().includes(e))) {
      return [d];
    }
    var { texts, urls } = d.getText().split(";").reduce((o, e) => {
      var [url, text] = e.trim().split(",");
      o.texts.push(text.trim());
      o.urls.push(url.trim());
      return o;
    }, { texts: [], urls: [] });
    var offset = 0;
    var delimiter = ", ";
    var r = d.copy().setText(texts.join(delimiter));
    urls.forEach((u, i) => {
      var start = offset;
      var end = offset + texts[i].length;
      r.setLinkUrl(start, end, u);
      offset = end + delimiter.length;
    });
    return [r.build()];
  });
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the column "D" (this is from `var cell = values[n][3];` of your script). And, each cell value is parsed to text and URL. And then, your expected result is obtained.

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setRichTextValues(RichTextValue))

Comment: Thank you!! That was indeed what I wanted and it worked! Do you have a recommendation for a better format for the list of url/text pairs? Better, meaning, a format that would work better with Apps Script. For instance would `url, text, url, text, url, text` be easier or more difficult or about the same to convert?

Comment: @Meghan M. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Do you have a recommendation for a better format for the list of url/text pairs?`, I think that your current format using `;` and `,` is not bad. Because a pair of URL and text can be split by `;`, and the text and the URL can be split by `,`. I think that this can be used. For example, when the text and the URL are split by `,` and a pair is also split by `,`, it is required to split the value every 2 `,`.

Comment: There's no Accpet button on my page. Not enough points? Let me know how to address that please! I did find one small problem. The modified links start on row 0 instead of row 1. Row 0, Column D should have the same label "shelves".

Comment: Changing D1 to D2 in `.getRange("D2:D"+...` fixed the problem.

Comment: @Meghan M. Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I have been trying to understand your new issue because I couldn't understand `row 0`. But from `Changing D1 to D2 in .getRange("D2:D"+... fixed the problem.`, I understood that you wanted to use from the 2nd row. I'm glad your issues were resolved.